# Making a sprite move

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class UnitMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Vector3 MousePos = Input.mousePosition;
            GetComponent<Transform>().position = (MousePos);
        }
    }
}
```

What is above is my code and every time I build and run the game the sprite will not go to the position of my mouse clicks but instead just disappears.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`Input.mousePosition` provides a [screen coordinate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html). This ranges from (0,0) to (`Screen.width`, `Screen.height`). The `Transform` component uses world coordinates. Try looking at its position value after clicking the sprite and see if the `X` and `Y` values look like pixel counts.

Use [`Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) to transform screen coordinates into world space.